# Using bash variable substitution instead of cut/awk

Tags: bash, awk, cut

Can I use bash variable substitution to extract a piece of a variable based on a delimeter?  I'm trying to get the immediate directory name of a filename (in this case, `foo`).

```
$ filename=./foo/bar/baz.xml
```

I know I could do something like

```
echo $filename | cut -d '/' -f 2
```

or

```
echo $filename | awk -F '/' '{print $2}'
```

but it's getting slow to fork `awk`/`cut` for multiple filenames.

I did a little profiling of the various solutions, using my real files:

echo | cut:

```
real    2m56.805s
user    0m37.009s
sys     1m26.067s
```

echo | awk:

```
real    2m56.282s
user    0m38.157s
sys     1m31.016s
```

@steeldriver's variable substitution/shell parameter expansion:

```
real    0m0.660s
user    0m0.421s
sys     0m0.235s
```

@jai_s's IFS-wrangling:

```
real    1m26.243s
user    0m13.751s
sys     0m28.969s
```

Both suggestions were a huge improvement over my existing ideas, but the variable substitution is fastest because it doesn't require forking any new processes.

Comment: https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameter-Expansion.html

Comment: Send all the filenames to one invocation of awk and it will be significantly faster than any solution in pure bash

Comment: Can you not use an array, do them all at once then put it in a new array ?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can remove the shortest leading substring that matches `*/`

```
tmp="${filename#*/}"
```

and then remove the longest trailing substring that matches `/*`

```
echo "${tmp%%/*}"
```

Answer (score 4):

```
    echo $f
    a/b/c

    $ (IFS='/';set $f; echo $1)
     a

    $ (IFS='/';set $f; echo $2)
     b

    $ (IFS='/';set $f; echo $3)
     c
```

with wild card it seems to work with double or single quotes -

```
    f="a?b?c"
     $(IFS="?"; set $f; echo $1)
     a
    echo $f
    a*b*c
    (IFS="*"; set $f; echo $1)
    a
```

yes, you'll have to unset the IFS back to default

```
    unset IFS
```

Comment: Ooh, I like that.

Comment: This is usually my preferred method as well, but bear in mind that Bash only supports `$1` through `$9` using this syntax. For 10th and later arguments, the `${10}` form must be used.

Comment: Doesn't work when `$f` contains wildcards. And you need to restore `IFS` afterwards (or do this in a command substitution, to get the value of a field, and that strips off trailing newlines).

Comment: The example works in isolation (inside Git bash on Windows), but when I pipe from the find command I get this error: `echo: write error: Bad address`.

Comment: Okay, looks like I have to `unset IFS` every time.

Comment: `unset IFS` vs `SAVIFS=$IFS` I do prefere the second... or it may unset IFS for the calling context?

Answer (score 1):

Feed the list to `awk` to speed it up:

```
awk -F '/' '{print $2}' < <(find /usr)
awk -F '/' '{print $2}' < inputfile
```

Demonstration:

```
time awk -F '/' '{print $2; SUM++} END {print "number of directories found: " SUM}' < <(find /usr -type d)
usr
usr
.
.
number of directories found: 16748

real    0m8.910s
user    0m0.050s
sys     0m0.050s
```

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use the "dirname" command, instead of all this awk/sed/cut stuff?

```
filename=./foo/bar/baz.xml
dirname $filename
```

Yields:

```
./foo/bar
```

Comment: In this case I was looking for the immediate directory, not the full directory path.