# Is there a parameter substitution/expansion alternative for "| cut -f1,2,3 -d:" a.k.a. trim after and including n-th character occurence?

Tags: string, cut, bash-expansion

An *ancient* version of `ipconfig` (inside initramfs) requires its user input to supply only up to 7 colon separated elements, like:

```
ip=client-ip:server-ip:gw-ip:netmask:hostname:device:autoconf
```

result in an `ipconfig` error when users do supply more than 7 elements.

Therefore the extra (2 DNS resolvers) should be chopped off.

That can be done inside a `subshell` with `cut`, like:

```
validated_input=$(echo ${user_input} | cut -f1,2,3,4,5,6,7 -d:)
```

**How can such `cut` be written using `(b)ash` parameter expansion/substitution?**

Without:

- launching subshell(s)/subprocess(es) (piping)
- IFS-wrangling/mangling

Because of (1) speed, see [Using bash variable substitution instead of cut/awk](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/253870/using-bash-variable-substitution-instead-of-cut-awk), and (2) learning.

---

In other words: How to do a lookup for n-th (7-th) character occurrence and remove/trim everything from there until the end of the string?

Comment: `IFS` mangling can be done locally if not mangling with the original ?

Comment: I know it does not solve your question per se, but you can save one process with this: `validated_input=$(cut -f1-7 -d: <<< "$user_input")`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This uses only parameter expansion:

```
${var%:"${var#*:*:*:*:*:*:*:}"}
```

**Example**:

```
$ var=client-ip:server-ip:gw-ip:netmask:hostname:device:autoconf:morefields:another:youwantanother:haveanother:
$ echo "${var%:"${var#*:*:*:*:*:*:*:}"}"
client-ip:server-ip:gw-ip:netmask:hostname:device:autoconf
```

Thanks ilkkachu for coming up with a fix to the trailing `:`!

---

```
${parameter#word}
${parameter##word}
```

> The word is expanded to produce a pattern just as in filename expansion (see Filename Expansion). If the pattern matches the beginning of the expanded value of parameter, then the result of the expansion is the expanded value of parameter with the shortest matching pattern (the ‘#’ case) or the longest matching pattern (the ‘##’ case) deleted. If parameter is ‘@’ or ‘*’, the pattern removal operation is applied to each positional parameter in turn, and the expansion is the resultant list. If parameter is an array variable subscripted with ‘@’ or ‘*’, the pattern removal operation is applied to each member of the array in turn, and the expansion is the resultant list.

This will attempt to match the *beginning* of your parameter, and if it does it will strip it.

**Example**:

```
$ var=a:b:c:d:e:f:g:h:i
$ echo "${var#a}"
:b:c:d:e:f:g:h:i
$ echo "${var#a:b:}"
c:d:e:f:g:h:i
$ echo "${var#*:*:}"
c:d:e:f:g:h:i
$ echo "${var##*:}"    # Two hashes make it greedy
i
```

---

```
${parameter%word}
${parameter%%word}
```

> The word is expanded to produce a pattern just as in filename expansion. If the pattern matches a trailing portion of the expanded value of parameter, then the result of the expansion is the value of parameter with the shortest matching pattern (the ‘%’ case) or the longest matching pattern (the ‘%%’ case) deleted. If parameter is ‘@’ or ‘*’, the pattern removal operation is applied to each positional parameter in turn, and the expansion is the resultant list. If parameter is an array variable subscripted with ‘@’ or ‘*’, the pattern removal operation is applied to each member of the array in turn, and the expansion is the resultant list.

This will attempt to match the *end* of your parameter, and if it does it will strip it.

**Example**:

```
$ var=a:b:c:d:e:f:g:h:i
$ echo "${var%i}"
a:b:c:d:e:f:g:h:
$ echo "${var%:h:i}"
a:b:c:d:e:f:g
$ echo "${var%:*:*}"
a:b:c:d:e:f:g
$ echo "${var%%:*}"    # Two %s make it greedy
a
```

---

So in the answer:

```
${var%:"${var#*:*:*:*:*:*:*:}"}
```

(note the quotes around `${var#...}` so that it is treated as a literal string (not a pattern) to be stripped off the end of `$var`).

When applied to:

```
var=client-ip:server-ip:gw-ip:netmask:hostname:device:autoconf:morefields:another:youwantanother:haveanother:
```

`${var#*:*:*:*:*:*:*:}` = `morefields:another:youwantanother:haveanother:`

That is expanded inside `${var%: ... }` like so:

`${var%:morefields:another:youwantanother:haveanother:}`

So you are saying give me:

```
client-ip:server-ip:gw-ip:netmask:hostname:device:autoconf:morefields:another:youwantanother:haveanother:
```

But trim `:morefields:another:youwantanother:haveanother:` off the end.

The Bash Reference Manual ([3.5.3](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Shell-Parameter-Expansion))

Comment: `echo "${var%:${var#*:*:*:*:*:*:*:}}"`, i.e. add the colon in an appropriate place in the first one? (expansions like that always make feel like something might break if the inner expansion produces a wildcard, but I think it works anyway.)

Comment: @Jesse_b Shouldn't the "Possible solution 2" be a separate answer? It complicates answer #1 for a reason I can't find. The Bash reference manual manual doesn't help me either. It explains all constructs but doesn't help me to find a solution for my question. Partly because my thinking is limited to 1 step solutions, like `cut` there is 1 command to get the job done, here it requires 1. identifying the excess part `var#` and 2 remove it. After reading the manual I don't understand why `var=1:2:3:4:5:6:;echo "${var%:${var#*:*:*:*:*:*:*:}}"` output `1:2:3:4:5:6:` doesn't remove the last colon...

Comment: @Jesse_b I've got a hard time figuring out why it works. `var=1:2:3:4:5:6:;echo ${var%:1:2:3:4:5:6:}` doesn't trim the last colon: `1:2:3:4:5:6:`. Where `var=1:2:3:4:5:6:;echo "${var%:}"` does trim the last colon `1:2:3:4:5:6`. I am trying to explain in your answer. Undo or improve my future explain edit.

Comment: @ProBackup Updated the answer.

Comment: Pretty nice +1. Did you run some speed test comparing your solution to @ilkkachu's?

Comment: @PesaThe I just did and both my solution and his regex solution run in `0.000s` consistently.   His script runs between `0.007` and `0.012`s.  So honestly speed shouldn't be an issue with any of the solutions.

Answer (score 5):

With a regex:

```
$ var=a:b:c:d:e:f:g:h:i:j:k:l
$ [[ $var =~ ([^:]*:){6}([^:]*) ]] && echo "${BASH_REMATCH[0]}"
a:b:c:d:e:f:g
```

This should work in standard shell:

```
#!/bin/sh
var=a:b:c:d:e:f:g:h:i:j:k:l
while true; do 
    case "$var" in
        *:*:*:*:*:*:*:*) var=${var%:*} ;;
        *) break ;;
    esac
done
echo "$var"
```

Or if we do allow setting `IFS` for the duration of `read`:

```
$ IFS=: read -a arr <<< "$var"
$ arr=("${arr[@]:0:7}")
$ echo "${arr[@]}"
a b c d e f g
$ printf "%s:%s:%s:%s:%s:%s:%s\n" "${arr[0]}" "${arr[1]}" "${arr[2]}" "${arr[3]}" "${arr[4]}" "${arr[5]}"  "${arr[6]}" 
a:b:c:d:e:f:g
```

Comment: The regex outputs a blank line with bash 3.2; the case (2nd) works correctly with bash 3.2

Comment: @ProBackup, hmm, it works for me (`GNU bash, version 3.2.57(1)-release`). regex support was added in 3.0, according to http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/scripting/bashchanges

Comment: I tested with `GNU bash, version 3.2.53(1)-release`. On `GNU bash, version 4.4.12(1)-release` the regex solution works as expected.

Answer (score 0):

In `zsh`:

```
$ ip=client-ip:server-ip:gw-ip:netmask:hostname:device:autoconf:x:y:z
$ echo ${(j(:))${"${(@s(:))ip}"[1,7]}}
client-ip:server-ip:gw-ip:netmask:hostname:device:autoconf
```

- `${(s(:))var}` split on `:`
- `"${(@)...}"`: make sure to preserve empty elements (like in `"$@"`)
- `${var[1,7]}` elements 1 to 7
- `${(j(:))var}` join elements on `:`

Or you can do:

```
$ set -o extendedglob
$ echo ${(M)ip##([^:]#:)(#c0,6)[^:]#}
client-ip:server-ip:gw-ip:netmask:hostname:device:autoconf
```

- `${var##pattern}` like in ksh, strip the longest leading portion matching the pattern.
- `(M)`: expanded to the **M**atched portion instead of stripping it
- `x#`: 0 or more `x`s (like regexp `*`)
- `(#c0,6)` from 0 to 6 of the preceding atom (like ksh's `{x,y}(...)`)

Comment: These question includes "in bash parameter expansion". The environment is initramfs ash (which I have now included in the question), so there is no zsh or ksh or even full bash available.

Comment: @ProBackup, OK. The answer can still be useful to others.